# PowerShell - How do I call a cmdlet in a function when overriding that cmdlet's name with the same name as the function?

Tags: function, powershell, redefinition, powershell-cmdlet

So I have a cmdlet named update-name that I have no access to change.

I have created a function named update-name (the same name as the cmdlet).  How do I call the cmdlet from the function with the same name?

I've tried a few things and none of them seem to work.

```
function update-name {
param([string] something)
  #call cmdlet update-name here
}
```

There is a way to do it when it is just functions:

```
$unBackup = 'DefaultUpdateName'
if(!(Test-Path Function:\$unBackup)) {
    Rename-Item Function:\Update-Name $unBackup
}

function update-name {
  & $unName
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work if it is a CmdLet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You the cmdlet's module name to disambiguate the names:

```
PS> Get-Command Start-Process | Format-Table ModuleName

ModuleName
----------
Microsoft.PowerShell.Management

PS> Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Start-Process Notepad
```

Comment: Is it better to go this route or the route of the answer I received off of twitter (somewhere in this set of answers)?

Comment: Both will work unless you have multiple cmdlets with the same name in which case 'Get-Command <blah> -Type Cmdlet` will return multiple results.  I prefer the approach I propose because it is easier to tell which `cmdlet` you are using because the associated module name is spelled out in the script.

Comment: Good enough for me. Thank you sir.

Comment: Good example: $oc = Get-Command 'Write-Host' -Module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'

Answer (score 6):

This will do the trick as well - thanks Keith Dahlby! http://twitter.com/dahlbyk/status/55341994817503232

```
$unName=Get-Command 'Update-Name' -CommandType Cmdlet;

function update-name {
  & $unName
}
```

Comment: There may be multiple cmdlets called update-name. But if you module-qualify it (as per Keith's answer above,) the collision is much more unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a [proxy function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/04/extending-and-or-modifing-commands-with-proxies.aspx)?